# Network requests after force quit in iOS timing out

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I have an application which uses geo fences. As each fence is tripped, the app wakes up, it gets the location and sends it to the server. All is well.

However I notice from logs that anytime the user force quits the app, when the app wakes up and tries to send the request to the server, it always times out.

```
Error:Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." 
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x12de69eb0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork 
Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=<snipped>, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=<snipped>, 
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}},
```

I am not sure where even to start looking. I see the timestamps and it is indeed the timeout settings consistently. Any pointers as to why this is happening?

I am using NSURLConnection and friends to send the request up on iOS 9.2.

Comment: You should use NSUrlSessionDataTask with timeout, it will constantly connection with server connection until you gets some response

Comment: I do not want to keep trying. I want to get it once and then move on.